# "Sorted" function doesn't work in Python task

Tags: python

Here's my code:

```
def Descending_Order(num):
    return int(''.join(sorted(str(num).split(), reverse = True)))
print Descending_Order(0)
print Descending_Order(15)
print Descending_Order(123456789)
```

"num" is supposed to be printed in descending order, but the code doesn't work, although I don't have any errors. Any idea why it isn't being executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `split` is superfluous, redundant and the cause of your problem. The [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method of a string requires a delimiter which in your case there is none so defaults to consecutive whitespace. As your string does not have consecutive white-space, it results in a single list containing the number in string format as the only element.

```
>>> str('123456789').split()
['123456789']
```

Sorting the resultant list is invariant as what you are sorting is a list of a single element

```
>>> sorted(['123456789'])
['123456789']
```

Finally joining and converting it to an integer restores the original number

```
>>> int(''.join(sorted(['123456789'])))
123456789
```

It is worth mentioning that sorted expects a sequence, so a string would qualify enough to be sorted without splitting into individual digits

What you probably wanted is

```
>>> def Descending_Order(num):
    return int(''.join(sorted(str(num), reverse = True)))

>>> print Descending_Order(123456789)
987654321
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also split the numbers using [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), then sort the list that way:

```
def Descending_Order(num):

    digits = [digit for digit in list(str(num))]

    return int("".join(sorted(digits, reverse = True)))

# Output
>>> Descending_Order(123456789)
987654321
```